# Google App Engine Datastore Periodically Wiped

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm seeing some really odd behavior in one of my GAE apps where periodically (every few days or so), the entire datastore just seems to get wiped and it restarts fresh. I've searched high and low for possible reasons for this and have so far come up empty handed.

There's only 1 entity in the datastore, with 2 properties. I'm loading up the datastore by reading a CSV file and inserting the data. Here's what that code looks like:

```
filename = "data.csv"
rows = []
with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    lines = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for line in lines:
        prop1Value = line[0]
        prop2Value = line[1]
        aRow = SomeEntity(prop1=prop1Value, prop2=prop2Value)
        rows.append(aRow)

chunkSize = 50
numProgressChunks = int(len(rows) / chunkSize) + 1

for puttableRows in chunks(rows, chunkSize):
    db.put(puttableRows)
```

This is the only time that data gets written to the datastore. It works, after I import the CSV I'm able to do queries and fetch data. Then a few days later I find that the data is gone. Not only are all rows gone, but the entity (kind) is no longer present in the GAE Datastore Viewer, whereas when I delete all the rows myself, the kind still shows up.

This might be a coincidence, but the last time the data got wiped, I noticed that a GAE instance was started up around the same time (within a few minutes).

This is an HRD app, with python2.7, using django. There are no deploys around the time that it gets reset. I've looked at the logs and can't find anything odd happening around the time of the reset.

What am I missing?

Comment: My theory would be that the entity somehow gets deleted; the instances are then automatically garbage-collected. Now, why the entity might be deleted, I cannot guess.

Comment: Also, is this on the dev server or on line?